# How to make a submit button with text + image in it?

Tags: html, image, button, input, submit

I would like to have a submit button that contains text *and* an image. Is this possible?

I can get the exact look I want with code that looks like:

```
<button type="button">
<img src="save.gif" alt="Save icon"/>
<br/>
Save
</button>
```

... but I haven't found a way to have one of those for my forms.
Is there a way to do that with an

```
<input type="submit" ...>
```

element? Or am I forced to go the *image or text* way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12435570/1491212

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`input type="submit"` is the best way to have a submit button in a form. The downside of this is that you cannot put anything other than text as its value. The button element can contain other HTML elements and content.

Try putting `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"` in your `button` element ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)).

Pay particular attention however to the following from that page:

> If you use the button element in an HTML form, different browsers will submit different values. Internet Explorer will submit the text between the `<button>` and `</button>` tags, while other browsers will submit the content of the value attribute. Use the input element to create buttons in an HTML form.

Answer (score 62):

Let's say your image is a 16x16 .png icon called icon.png  Use the power of CSS!

CSS:

```
input#image-button{
    background: #ccc url('icon.png') no-repeat top left;
    padding-left: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" id="image-button" value="Text"></input>
```

This will put the image to the left of the text.

Comment: what does `#ccc url('icon.png')` mean?

Comment: what does `#ccc url('icon.png')` mean?

Comment: That is just a hex color close to light gray

Answer (score 11):

You're really close to the answer yourself

```
<button type="submit">
<img src="save.gif" alt="Save icon"/>
<br/>
Save
</button>
```

Or, you can just remove the type-attribute

```
<button>
<img src="save.gif" alt="Save icon"/>
<br/>
Save
</button>
```

Answer (score 11):

In case [dingbats/icon fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat) are an option, you can use them instead of images.

The following uses a combination of

- [an icon font (e.g. Font Awesome)](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/),
- [character encodings in HTML (e.g. `&#xf090`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#HTML_character_references)
- [the Unicode code point of the icon you want to use (e.g. `&#xf090` for the *sign in* logo)](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/signin/),
- CSS:

In HTML:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<form name="signin" action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text-input" placeholder="&#xf183; your username" class="stylish"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="&#xf090; sign in" class="stylish"/>
</form>
```

In CSS:

```
.stylish {
    font-family: georgia, FontAwesome;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Abdull/MhNjL/)

Notice the `font-family` specification: all characters/code points will use `georgia`, falling back to `FontAwesome` for any code points `georgia` doesn't provide characters for. `georgia` doesn't provide  any characters in the [*private use* range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29), [exactly where `FontAwesome` has placed its icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/).

Answer (score 5):

I have found a very easy solution! If you have a form and you want to have a custom submit button you can use some code like this:

```
<button type="submit">
    <img src="login.png" onmouseover="this.src='login2.png';" onmouseout="this.src='login.png';" />
</button>
```

Or just direct it to a link of a page.

Answer (score 2):

`<input type="button" id="btnTexWrapped" style="background:` `url('http://i0006.photobucket.com/albums/0006/findstuff22/Backgrounds/bokeh2backgrounds.jpg');background-size:30px;width:50px;height:3em;" />`

Change input style elements as you want to get the button you need.

I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting.
I have been able to get my form to work but the resulting email displays:

imageField_x: 80
imageField_y: 17

at the bottom of the email that I get.

Here's my code for the buttons.

```
    <tr>
      <td><input type="image" src="images/sendmessage.gif" / ></td>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="image" src="images/printmessage.gif"onclick="window.print()"></td>
    </tr>
```

Maybe this will help you and me as well.

:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

HTML code:

```
    <form action="submit.php" method="get" id="form">        
    <a href="javascript: submitForm()">        
    <img src="save.gif" alt="Save icon"/>        
    <br/>        
    save        
    </a>        
    </form>
```

note: you can use and action and method of your choice and Id and any text starting from href="javascript: and ending to ()" but make sure that when I type the same things such as id and some text you type in your replacement in the same places(java script and HTML code).

java script code:

```
    var form=document.getElementById("form");        
    function submitForm()        
    {        
    form.submit();       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other example:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" style="border: none; background-color: white">
```

Answer (score 0):

With svg:

```css
input#image-button {
  background: url( "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='https://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 150 150'%3E%3Cpath d='M10 10h123v123H10z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E" ) no-repeat  5px /* image padding */;
padding-left: 16px; /* select the indentation to the text */
}
```

[Image position adjustment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

[SVG-encoder](https://codepen.io/yoksel/details/MWKeKK)