# Font-awesome, input type 'submit'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails, font-awesome

There seems to be no class for input type 'submit' in font-awesome. Is it possible to use some class from font-awesome for button input? I've added icons to all buttons (which actually links with class 'btn' from twitter-bootstrap) in my applications, but can't add icons on 'input type submit'.

Or, how to use this code:

```
input#image-button{
    background: #ccc url('icon.png') no-repeat top left;
    padding-left: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

html:

```
<input type="submit" id="image-button">Text</input>
```

(which I took from [HTML: How to make a submit button with text + image in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621891/html-how-to-make-a-submit-button-with-text-image-in-it)) with font-awesome?

Answer (score 388, accepted):

use button type="submit" instead of input

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-lg"></i> Next
</button>
```

for Font Awesome 3.2.0 use

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-large"></i> Next
</button>
```

Comment: Awesome! Works as expected. Still need some steps to adapt this for simple_form or create a helper, but it is relatively easy.

Comment: Also be aware of the differences between `<button type=submit>` and `<input type=submit>`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543615/difference-between-input-type-submit-and-button-type-submittext-button

Comment: @stanislav-mayorov it does work. If you are using current version 4.7 you have to adjust from 3.2.0 (from 2012). Try the updated answer.

Comment: @JoaoLeme does `<button type="submit">` work to any form?

Comment: This doesn't work when I want to avoid reloading the page.

Answer (score 102):

## HTML

Since `<input>` element displays only value of value attribute, we have to manipulate only it:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn fa-input" value="&#xf043; Input">
```

I'm using `&#xf043;` entity here, which corresponds to the U+F043, the Font Awesome's 'tint' symbol.

## CSS

Then we have to style it to use the font:

```
.fa-input {
  font-family: FontAwesome, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Which will give us the tint symbol in Font Awesome and the other text in the appropriate font.

However, this control will not be pixel-perfect, so you might have to tweak it by yourself.

Comment: Thank for answer, it works, but I can't actually use this approach, because font affects entire value's text. I'm also use 'icon-large' in other buttons... For those who will try this, font codes is here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/sass/font-awesome.scss

Comment: I think that's all we can do here. Personally I suggest you to leave `<input>`s w/o an icon.

Comment: worked fine, I have to use <input type="submit">   because I have two submit in one form

Comment: this is better than adding "fa" to element' class, since "fa" will change the element's height.

Comment: Also you may use inline style `font-family` property to use it in any HTML elements that has text content.

Comment: this is the best answer!

Answer (score 57):

You can use font awesome utf cheatsheet

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="&#xf011; Login"/>
```

here is the link for the cheatsheet
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: This made my day! Thanks.. For any other users, please note the sentence: _copy and paste the icons (**not the unicode**) directly from this page into your design_ i.e. copy the actual icon and it will work

Comment: `<input type="button" class="fa" value="&#xf011; Login"/>` without bootstrap  use fa class to get it working

Comment: If you're trying to set this with javascript or jQuery, use the unicode variation: `$("input.search").addClass("fa").val("\uf011 Login");`

Comment: Even with Bootstrap I need to add class="fa" to get this working.

Comment: This produces just a rectangle for me. Shame

Answer (score 13):

Well, technically it's not possible to get `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements work on `input` elements

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content):

> #### 12.1 The :before and :after pseudo-elements
>
> Authors specify the style and location of generated content with the
>   :before and :after pseudo-elements. As their names indicate, the
>   :before and :after pseudo-elements specify the location of content
>   before and after an element's document tree content. The 'content'
>   property, in conjunction with these pseudo-elements, specifies what is
>   inserted.

---

So I had a project where I had submit buttons in the form of `input` tags and for some reason the other developers restricted me to use `<button>` tags instead of the usual input submit buttons, so I came up with another solution, of wrapping the buttons inside a `span` set to `position: relative;` and then absolutely positioning the icon using `:after` pseudo.

> Note: The demo fiddle uses the content code for FontAwesome 3.2.1 so
>   you may need to change the value of `content` property accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<span><input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" /></span>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="submit"] {
    margin: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

span {
    position: relative;
}

span:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f004"; /* Value may need to be changed in newer version of font awesome*/
    font-size: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 1px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GrBJF/)</kbd>

Now here everything is self explanatory here, about one property i.e `pointer-events: none;`, I've used that because on hovering over the `:after` pseudo generated content, your button won't click, so using the value of `none` will force the click action to go pass through that content.

From [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) :

> In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of mouse
>   events, the value none instructs the mouse event to go "through" the
>   element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.

Hover the heart font/icon <kbd><s>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GrBJF/1/)</s></kbd> and see what happens if you DON'T use `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: While a very cool solution it has one big downside: pointer-events: none is not supported by IE<11 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events). The reason being that pointer-events property was made for SVG elements (vector graphics) and it's not technically in the W3C specs for other HTML elements (yet, https://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css4-ui#pointer-events) even though all modern browsers except for IE<11 support it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use button classes `btn-link` and `btn-xs` with type `submit`, which will make a small invisible button with an icon inside of it. Example:

```
<button class="btn btn-link btn-xs" type="submit" name="action" value="delete">
    <i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Also possible like this

```
<button type="submit" class="icon-search icon-large"></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

With multiple submits, when you need the value of the submit selected, this can be done quite easily. Just create a hidden field in your form and change its value depending on what button is clicked. For example, in the form, say you have:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Clicked" name="Clicked" value="" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ClickCheck" id="Create"> <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"> Create Bill</i></button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ClickCheck" id="Reset"> <i class="fa fa-times"> Reset</i></button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ClickCheck" id="StoreData"> <i class="fa fa-archive"> Save</i></button>
```

Using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.ClickCheck').click(function()
        {
            var ButtonID = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#Clicked').val(ButtonID);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then you can retrieve the value of the button clicked in the "Clicked" post variable

Answer (score 0):

**Copy the actual symbol into the submit value attributes**

```
<input type="submit" value="Send ➢ ➔ " class="btn btn-default" />
```