# How to embed font-awesome icons into submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-rails, font-awesome

Trying to user font awesome icons for my buttons but I cant get it to show in the submit_tag

```
 <%= submit_tag icon("search"), class: "btn-primary", style:"width:40px;" %>
```

output:

```
 <input class="btn-primary" name="commit" style="width:40px;" type="submit" value="&lt;i class='icon-search' style='font-size:1em' &gt;&lt;/i&gt;">
```

helper:

```
def icon(name, size=1)
  #icon("camera-retro")
  #<i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> 

  html = "<i class='icon-#{name}' "
  html += "style='font-size:#{size}em' "
  html += "></i>"
  html.html_safe
end
```

when I remove the html.html_safe line of the helper I get the same thing. its like html_safe is not working. I have also tried html = raw(html) with no effect either.

Comment: Can you get Font Awesome icons to work at all as input values?

Comment: You can do this if you change the submit to a button. See [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686007/font-awesome-input-type-submit).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Input submit tags don't allow nested HTML, which you need to show an icon.

Try using a button instead:

```
<button class='btn btn-primary' style='width:40px;'>
  <%= icon("search") %>
</button>
```

It's worth noting some differences between the behaviour of button tags and input submit tags.  Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use) for a bunch of great details.  I personally haven't had issues using button tags in my applications.  YMMV with respect to different browsers and such, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= link_to(status, :method=>:delete) do %>
   <i class='icon-trash icon-large'></i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add icons to your HTML code, like this:

```
<i class="icon-search"></i>
```

However, if you want place icons in Rails link_to helper use the ilink_to helper method. Follow the steps below:

1) Add the gem to your assets group in the Gemfile:
    gem 'less-rails-fontawesome'

2) Run *bundle install*:

3) Be sure that *@import 'fontawesome';* is uncommented in app/assets/stylesheetes/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less.

4) Use *ilink_to* helper method instead of *link_to* helper method.

```
<%= ilink_to "upload-alt", "Edit", edit_post_path(post), class: 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

Obs: Precede the link text with the icon name stripped off icon- prefix

These instructions are here: https://github.com/wbzyl/less-rails-fontawesome

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to get rid of `html_safe` from the helper, and use `raw icon("search")` instead of just `icon("search")`

and as BaronVonBraun says - use `button` rather than `input[submit]`