# Proper way to render fa_icons in helpers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails 4.2 application that has a rating system. I want to move the presenter logic into a helper. I want to show either a star or a half-star depending on whether the ranking is whole.

```
module ThingHelper
  def calculate_stars(thing)
    output = ""
    total = thing.overall_average

    thing.overall_average.ceil.times do |n| 
      if total >= 1
        output += content_tag(:i, "<%= fa_icon 'star' %>")
        total -= 1
      else  
        output += content_tag(:i, "<%= fa_icon 'star-half' %>")
      end
    end   
    return output
  end
end
```

In my erb template I have this:

```
<%= calculate_stars(thing).html_safe %>
```

However, it just lists out the strings like this: "<%= fa_icon 'star' %>".  I have tried using `raw` as well as using `concat` instead of `+=` but both attempted solutions just render a string.

I have also tried without the `content_tag` helper but that isn't working.

I have consulted the following: 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag, [How to embed font-awesome icons into submit_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783061/how-to-embed-font-awesome-icons-into-submit-tag), [raw vs. html_safe vs. h to unescape html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html), and [Ruby on Rails display half a star for a decimal rating, e.g. 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888515/ruby-on-rails-display-half-a-star-for-a-decimal-rating-e-g-4-5).

What am I missing? Thanks

**Edit**

I'm not convinced this can be done in the helper so I just had to put the logic in the view. Basically, I round and calculate the number of full stars then have a conditional to add another based upon rounding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors you're making that are super-small.

First, is in the parameters you're giving to content tag. [Take a look at the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag). In the first example...

```
content_tag(:p, "Hello world!")
 # => <p>Hello world!</p>
```

The string is what goes *between* the tags. However, [Font Awesome icons](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) need to be set as the *class* of the tag, with *no content* between the `<i></i>`.

Which means you need to pass `content_tag` an empty string and a hash...

```
<%= content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa-icon star") %>
=> "<i class="fa_icon star"></i>"
```

I know you're doing other things to multiply stars and whatnot. I think you'll be able to take it from here...

Comment: Thanks.  This worked. The problem as you pointed you was the arguments I passed to `content_tag`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declared a string for output.

```
module ThingHelper
  def calculate_stars(thing)
    total = thing.overall_average

    thing.overall_average.ceil.times do |n| 
      if total >= 1
        content_tag(:i, :class => "fa fa-list") do
        end
        total -= 1
      else  
        content_tag(:i, :class => "fa fa-list") do
        end
      end
    end   
  end
end
```

Then render on your erb:

```
<%= calculate_stars(thing) %>
```

Note that I am using bootstrap and glyphicons for my icon. Just change the icon class.

I have tried this on my development and produced this:

[image]