# Font awesome icon and text in input submit button?

Tags: html, fonts, submit

I have a similar problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686007/font-awesome-input-type-submit#answer-22478072) , i want to place font awesome icon into my submit button and also a text, it looks so: http://prntscr.com/608exx

Content of my input submit value is Buy now `&nbsp;&#xf07a;`

The icon is visible because i set on input field `font-family: FontAwesome;` my question is, how can i set on my text inside the button standard font family?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Buy Now
                </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this whilst retaining the `<input>` element, you must put the Font Awesome glyph outside of the `<input>` and then simply position it on top.

```
<span><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart glyph"></i></span>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Basket" />
```

Then simply add some CSS to make the whole button clickable.

```
.glyph{
    position: relative;
    left: 35px;
    pointer-events: none; //this makes the glyph clickable as part of the input
}

.button{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjx8co0z/4/)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to change it only via CSS. Just need to pick up all types of tags attributes.

For example:

for buttons: input, [type="button"], [type="reset"], [type="submit"]
for text: input, [type="text"]
and etc...

```css
input, [type="button"], [type="reset"], [type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    background-color: #EF2B76;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
}

input, [type="text"] {
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
}
```