# Why is my icon font displayed as the hex value instead of the icon itself?

Tags: html, css, icons, fontello

I wanted to add the fontello icon in an input value

Here's the input code:

`<input style= "font-family: fontello;" id="mc4wp_submit" type="submit" value="&#xe800;"/>`

But the icon is shown as &#xe800 and not as a image

How do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Font Awesome Icon in Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder)

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686007/font-awesome-input-type-submit