# Add fontawesome icon to button generated via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, button

How can i add fontawesome icons to a button generated like this?

```
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>'  + "<input 
type='button' onclick='getTxtUrl(" + item.id + ")' style = 'width: 
32px; height: 28px;' class='btn btn-success'>" + '</td></tr>';
});
```

I've tried so many things and am going crazy. I'm sure it will turn out to be the stupidest thing, missing a ' or something. Help please!

Comment: Yes ir was quotes `$.each(response, function(i, item) {
  trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.name + 
    '</td><td><input type="button" onclick="getTxtUrl(\'' + item.id + '\')" style="width: 32 px; height: 28 px;" class="btn btn-success"></td></tr>';
});`

Comment: This is easier to read and can have breaklines `$.each(response, function(i, item) { trHTML += \`<tr><td>${item.name}</td><td><input type="button" onclick="getTxtUrl('${item.id}')" 
style="width: 32 px; height: 28 px;" class="btn btn-success"></td></tr>\`; });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `button` instead of `input` type button

```
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>'  + "<button onclick='getTxtUrl(" + item.id + ")' style = 'width: 32px; height: 28px;' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></button>" + '</td></tr>';
            });
```

Comment: Or you can use CSS for that.

Comment: @MonkeyD.Luffy, how? you can't add pseudo element to input

Comment: [ Font-awesome, input type 'submit' ] 
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686007/font-awesome-input-type-submit) Check solution by @Pavlo