# Add text on img type="button"

Tags: html, css

I have button like this

```
<img type="button" src="ans.png">
```

But I want to put text on this button.

However, `value=""` doesn't work.

It looks simple quesiton,but I couldn't find the right answer.

I appreciate any help??

Comment: can you use javascript or jquery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML: How to make a submit button with text + image in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621891/html-how-to-make-a-submit-button-with-text-image-in-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Cannot Make A Image Button With `<img type=button>`. but you can make a `<button>` and give a background image from `css`

```css
button{
  background: url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: It works well for me and thanks for adding `background-***` samples.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such thing as type attribute for the img tag. - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

if you want to put an image on a button you may have a button tag with an img tag inside it like this:

```html
<button id="close-image"><img src="http://example.com/path/to/image.png"></button>
```

or an input with image type like this:

```html
<input type="image" src="http://example.com/path/to/image.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image_buttton {
  position:relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width:100px;
  height: 35px // as the image height;
}
.image_buttton .img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:1
}
.image_buttton .img img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.image_buttton .text {
  position: relative;
  z-index:10;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="image_buttton">
  <span class="text">button text</span>
  <span class="img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<img />` tag used for embedding Image on HTML document. It doesn't have any `type` or `value` attribute.

If you want to show a background image on a button, try this:

**HTML**

```
<button class="image_buttton">button text</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);
 }
```